# using numeric or alphabetic codes in statements; for use in "if" statements

Tags: if-statement, cobol

I am wondering how to do something in COBOL. I am trying to write a program that uses if statements to output matching data records from a data file. But I have not done it like this yet see what I need to do is make codes for the different data types.

`blue = 1`
`brown = 2`.

So I tried it like this but it wouldn't work. This I have declared in the master-record:

```
01  COLOR-IN    PIC (9)
    05    BLUE         VALUE 1.
    05    BROWN        VALUE 2.
```

Then I figured I could just write an if statement like

```
IF COLOR-IN = BLUE 
   PERFORM 200-OUTPUT.
```

So what I am asking is how do I make the colors equal a numeric or alphabetic code. What kind of statement should I write.

I figured it out. I used the 88 statements. Like this

```
88      MALE     VALUE 'M'.
```

But I have another problem. The output does list the records that meet the 'if' statement criteria, however, I need to code in the program the actual hair and eye color so that when the program executes it prints the hair and eye color instead of 1 or 2. Can anyone give me an example or hint on how to do that?

Comment: Please show us the code as it is now.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "COBOL: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 for learning about 88s.  They are very useful.

A table (array) of labels that correspond to your values is what you're looking for.  If you use alphabetic codes, as in your 
88 MALE VALUE 'M' case, then your table has an entry for the value and for the label.

```
01  INPUT-VALUE                 PIC X(1).
    88  MALE                    VALUE "M".
    88  FEMALE                  VALUE "F".

01  LABELS-AND-VALUES-AREA.
    05  LABELS-AND-VALUES.
        07  ONE-LABEL-AND-VALUE OCCURS 2.
            09  ONE-LABEL       PIC X(6).
            09  ONE-VALUE       PIC X(1).
    05      FILLER REDEFINES LABELS-AND-VALUES
                                VALUE "MALE  MFEMALEF".
01  I                           PIC S9(4) COMP.
01  DISPLAY-LABEL               PIC x(6).

    MOVE "?" TO DISPLAY-LABEL
    PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I > 2
        IF INPUT-VALUE = ONE-VALUE(I)
            MOVE ONE-LABEL(I) TO DISPLAY-LABEL
        END-IF
    END-PERFORM
```

If you use numerics for your input values, you can skip the lookup and go right to the label you want.

```
01  INPUT-VALUE                 PIC 9(1).
    88  MALE                    VALUE "1".
    88  FEMALE                  VALUE "2".
    88  VALID-INPUT             VALUE "1", "2".

01  LABELS-AND-VALUES-AREA.
    05  LABELS-AND-VALUES.
        07  ONE-LABEL-AND-VALUE OCCURS 2.
            09  ONE-LABEL       PIC X(6).
    05      FILLER REDEFINES LABELS-AND-VALUES
                                VALUE "MALE  FEMALE".
01  DISPLAY-LABEL               PIC x(6).

   IF VALID-INPUT
       MOVE ONE-LABEL(INPUT-VALUE) TO DISPLAY-LABEL
   ELSE
       MOVE "?" TO DISPLAY-LABEL
   END-IF
```

For this case, you might want to add some code for missing/unknown data.

**Update**

I added some code to handle missing/unknown data.

Comment: That was incredibly helpful. Thank you :))))

Comment: Why not just EVALUATE or even IF?